# How to prevent other signals while still in a trade? (Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to code an indicator in Pine Script 4, but I do not wan´t multiple trade signals while another theoretical trade would still be active. I will add a "close position" alert later on but for now I only wan´t the first signal until the next green heikin ashi candle appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `var` to see if you are already in a trade.

This should give you an idea:

```
var is_long = false

is_green = (close > open)
is_red = not is_green

long_cond = not is_long and barstate.isconfirmed and is_green  // Enter only if we are not already long
short_cond = is_long and barstate.isconfirmed and is_red  // Enter only if we are already long

is_long := long_cond ? true : short_cond ? false : is_long  // Update the flag

// Reset the flag when you exit
```